# Get Average request hitting on server through nginx by command line

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to fetch average request hitting on server on 1 min data through command line.If anyone help me out of this will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not exactly sure, what you want to accomplish, I've got an ideas for you: just use netcat to grab requests directly from the internet:

```
netcat -k -l 1.2.3.4 8080 >/tmp/requests.log
```

Make sure to replace 1.2.3.4 with your server's IP address and 8080 with the port it is listening on (may be 80 e.g.). If your nginx server listens on IP 0.0.0.0, netcat will be able to grab any incoming requests and log them. If ngingx is listening on 1.2.3.4, you will have to stop it, before netcat can listen on 1.2.3.4 and the same port as ngingx.

Note, that on some Linux systems instead of `netcat` you have to type `nc` .

Also note, that whatever netcat grabs, nginx can't read, so your web site visitors will get error messages.

If the port number is below 1024, netcat needs root privilege to open the port.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use ngxtop for this

Comment: Hi @Gabor Vincze i know that we can use ngxtop to accomplish this task, But i need to use command line for this. If you have any idea its highly appreciate.

Comment: It is command line. Do you need something which just collects a minute then quits ?

Comment: Yeah. you can say that i need to collect average request / second or request /minute in variable to reflect on my view.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get average minute-level data from your existing logs, you'll want to do something like this:

`cat /var/log/nginx/access.log | sed -E 's/.[0-9]{2}/[A-Za-z]{3}/[0-9]{4}:([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})./\1/' | uniq -c`